# uploading file and data at the same time to php using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, upload

I have read so much about file uploads and data uploads using jquery and php but I don't seem to understand anything when it comes to sending  the both of them from jquery to php for upload at the same time.I have hard a hard time trying to figure this out on my own but I have not found any answers.All my internet searches have been in vain.I will be very happy if someone gives me guidelines or shows me the method used to do this.Thank you.